# What do double vertical lines mean?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

I am reading a [paper](http://www-ui.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~takeo/papers/rigid.pdf) on computer graphic and having hard time to understand this formula:

[image: formula01]

1. What is the double vertical lines means? Do they always go with power of 2?
2. If I want to learn further about this equation, which subset of math should I look into?

Comment: Without the $^2$, it means the distance between the first term and the second. But they are considering the square of the distance, largely because squares of distances are better behaved than distances.

Comment: In addition, you don't really need to look at a particular area of math to learn about this equation. You probably just need to know how to calculate the distances between two points and perhaps the triangle inequality.

Comment: When do people normally use the double vertical line? What is it called mathematically?

Comment: The word you a are looking for is "norm" or "normed space". wikipedia might help on this topic. Alternatively, in the case of finite dimensions any book/script on linear algebra should do it.

Comment: I found [these series of videos](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors_and_spaces/dot_cross_products/v/vector-dot-product-and-vector-length) that explained this from [KhanAcademy](https://www.khanacademy.org).